# Proper way to handle updating a view for Flask SPA using AJAX

Tags: python, ajax, view, flask

This is a high level architectural question because I do not have web development experience, and I haven't found any succinct answers online.

Say I have a Flask app that starts off has a very simple html page with a few form fields.  You key in some data into the form fields, submit, and the submission triggers an AJAX call onclick which then posts the results to your flask route.

When it comes time to display the data, you pull it out of the requests object which was posted to the relevant view, and then render a template passing through your formatted data.

My question is... if you want to continually make updates to the same page, how does that work?  For example maybe after the first post hits your view you show a chart on the page with information passed to that view from the route. If you then decide to get a new graph for a different set of inputs to the form data, since you aren't hitting a new route do you just basically reload the page whenever the user keys in new data to the form fields and submits?  How does this work if you want subsequent data to pop up after the chart?  Do you just have multiple divs hidden/chilling in the background that unhide whenever certain events occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you usually use jquery to populate a div something like

```
<form id="my_form"> ... </form><button id="my_button">Clicky</button>
<div id="info_div"></div>
<script>
$("#my_button").click(function(){
   var data = $("#my_form").serialize()
   $("#info_div").load("/url/of/bit/to/load?"+data)
})</script>
```